# How to get tax amount(both group and percent) individual product in account_invoice(Sale)?

Tags: odoo-10

While creating report I need to take tax amount for individual product from account.invoice **(sale)**. Have tried SQL query but it is not possible so how can I do that?

Comment: Your question has tags `openerp` and `odoo-10`. Which one is this question about?

Comment: this question belongs to odoo-10

Answer (score 0):

A SQL query *is* possible but it could get hard if you try to make the calculations in pure SQL. `account.invoice.line` has a Many2many field `invoice_line_tax_ids` that you can use in your SQL query as a mapping table (database table `account_invoice_line_tax` that has fields `invoice_line_id` and `tax_id`).

If you want to make this job easier for yourself, create a new computed field (remember `store=True`) for `account.invoice.line` that calculates the taxes by line using the same methods Odoo uses. See [`account.invoice.line._compute_price` for example](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/10.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L1154).

If you need the taxes by *product* instead of by *invoice line*, just group the invoice lines by product in your report.